# Highlighting text in MathJax crashes the app

Tags: bug, ios-app, mathjax

When I highlight text between two $'s on sites that support MathJax, the app crashes.

- App Version: 1.6.5.4
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: What's the downvote for?

Comment: Do you have specific examples?  I've not been able to reproduce this.